# How to list from AD disabled users with OU & manager info

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I get a list of disabled user accounts in the domain, including the `OU` and `Manager` fields? I got it work with only users and `DistinguishedName`, but `Manager` data causes problems.

Tried this, but didn't work:

```
Get-ADUser -Server fabrik.com -Filter * -Property DisplayName, Manager, OU | 
    Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq "False" } |
    Select-Object DisplayName, @{ n = 'OU'; e = { ($_.canonicalname -Split "/")[-2] } }, Manager |
    Export-Csv "c:\temp\DisabledUsers.csv"
```

I tested also the `Search-ADObject` function, but didn't get it to work either.

Comment: error message or description of the behiavor?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -Server fabrik.com -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -Property distinguishedname,canonicalname,DisplayName,Manager,OU | Select DisplayName, @{ n = 'OU'; e = { ($_.canonicalname -Split "/")[-2] } }, @{ n = 'Manager'; e = { $_ -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2' } } | Export-Csv "c:\temp\DisabledUsers.csv"
```